# Back Ground Sound in Android

Tags: android

For Playing different sounds I have made a class SoundManager using soundpool now I can play a wanted sound on button click by my activities.But I want a back ground sound which will play through out my whole game ,from one activity to other.So how can I do it using SoundPool and where I have to write code to play it in my Activities.
Actually I am new to Android if is there any other better way for playing background sounds through out all activities  please tell me

Here is my SoundManger class Code.

```
package com.Tutorial.Sound;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;


public class SoundManager {

    static private SoundManager _instance;
    private static SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private static AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private static Context mContext;

    private SoundManager()
    {   
    }


    static synchronized public SoundManager getInstance() 
    {
        if (_instance == null) 
          _instance = new SoundManager();
        return _instance;
     }


    public static  void initSounds(Context theContext) 
    { 
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
    } 


    public static void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
    }


    public static void loadSounds()
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.starwars, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(2, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.terminator, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(3, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.soundfcgo, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(4, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.soundfc1, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(5, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.soundfc2, 1));
    }


    public static void playSound(int index,float speed) 
    {       
             float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
             streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
             mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, speed); 
    }


    public static void stopSound(int index)
    {
        mSoundPool.stop(mSoundPoolMap.get(index));
        mSoundPool.pause(mSoundPoolMap.get(index));
    }

    public static void cleanup()
    {
        mSoundPool.release();
        mSoundPool = null;
        mSoundPoolMap.clear();
        mAudioManager.unloadSoundEffects();
        _instance = null;

    }
}
```

If you have any example on this back ground sound topic , it will be great full to me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class to resolve your problem. It gives you the possibility to play music and sounds in background, whatever activity is currently in foreground. Hope this helps.

Comment: can't i use sound pool for BG sound

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer to this question, since I've always been using Sound Pool only for playing short sounds and Media Player for playing a soundtrack in background.